# R is partial order, $B_1 \subseteq A$ and $B_2 \subseteq A$, prove that $x$ is an upper bound of $B_1$ iff $x$ is an upper bound of $B_2$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> $R$ is a partial order on $A$.
>
> $B_1 \subseteq A$
>
> $B_2 \subseteq A$
>
> $\forall x \in B_1 \exists y \in B_2 (xRy)$
>
> $\forall x \in B_2 \exists y \in B_1 (xRy)$
>
> Prove that for all $x \in A$, x is an upper bound of $B_1$ iff $x$ is
>   an upper bound of $B_2$.

My attempt:

$(\rightarrow)$
Suppose $x$ is an upper bound of $B_1$.

It means $\forall b \in B_1(bRx)$

Take arbitrary $y \in B_2$. There exists $b \in B_1$ such that $yRb$. We also know that $bRx$. Since $R$ is partial order, we have $yRx$. $y$ was arbitrary, so we have

$$\forall y \in B_2(yRx)$$

Hence $x$ is upper bound of $B_2$.

$(\leftarrow)$  (Nearly identical)

Suppose $x$ is upper bound of $B_2$. Then for all $b \in B_2$ we have $bRx$.

Take arbitrary $y \in B_1$. There exists $b \in B_2$ such that $yRb$. We also know that $bRx$. $R$ is partial order, hence $yRx$. $y$ was arbitrary, hence we conclude that $x$ is upper bound for $B_1$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Where in the proof do you feel any uncertainty?

Comment: @Berci, thanks for the  review. Nothing specific, just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.